# How to turn off laptop beeping due to screen failed

Tags: laptop, display

my DELL N5110 felt on the ground and broke the screen. 
All the screen is white and it dims after a while doing nothing.

Fortunately, I have a monitor and I can use laptop with it.

PROBLEM:
The computer is beeping due to screen error (8 times again and again) and I don't know how to turn this sound off.
It's beeping from speakers.

Now I'm using Linux Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: You can try and disconnect the monitor but if the beeping doesn't stop there is likely other reasons its beeping.

Comment: I've just tried this..doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

8 Beeps is definitely to do with the monitor not functioning correctly. Since you haven't mentioned this yet, is the monitor physically broken or just 'not working'? If it's not physically broken, it probably just has a loose cable. Judging by the amount of posts about this it could be a common issue with this model as you can see below.

I found a [Dell Community thread](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/t/19432846.aspx) regarding this topic with a couple methods mentioned that you could try if you feel up to it.

Here are some of the suggestions users have come up with in that thread:

> Eight beeps means a display failure.
>
> Since the external monitor works, you know it's not a fault with the video card.
>
> **With the notebook off, hold down the "D" key and power the notebook on.  If you get solid colors on the screen, then you know the LCD is good.**  I would look for a problem with the video cable.  Just resently, someone found that the front bezel was creating a problem with the video cable.

Here's another:

> I encountered the same issue.  The laptop had fallen from a table approximately 2-feet above the floor.  Upon subsequently attempting to start the N5110 Dell laptop, I saw a white screen and heard 8 beeps.  The screen did not change from all-white, and the beeps would resume approximately every 15-seconds.
>
> My solution was to open the computer so that I could see the motherboard.  Watch any of a number of videos on youtube for guidance if you are unfamiliar with the technique for properly disassembling and reassembling the N5110 chassis.  I removed the CMOS battery from its case on the left-front of the motherboard, After a minute I placed the same battery back into the socket.  Taking care to reconnect the three electrical ribbons that run from the motherboard to the keyboard, the battery was replaced and the start button was pushed.
>
> A boot notice appeared on the screen that the computer had been improperly shut-down, and I had the option of restoring to a previous point, or starting Windows normally.  I selected the normal start, and after a longer than usual boot, the laptop returned to full functioning.
>
> I don't know if the ol' CMOS battery trick will work in all instances of the dreaded 8-beep error, but pulling the battery and replacing it causes the system to perform a power reset.  I wish you similar success should you encounter this issue.

<strike>And finally, an entire Dell Community tag dedicated to the [N5110 White Screen 8 Beeps](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/tags/N5110+White+Screen+8_2D00_beeps/default.aspx) issue.</strike> This tag only has one post.

If you feel up to opening up your laptop the [Dell Service Manual](ftp://ftp.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_laptop/esuprt_inspiron_laptop/inspiron-15r-n5110_Service%20Manual_en-us.pdf) should provide you with enough information on how you can check the monitor cable.

Comment: Thank you, Michael. It's strange how CMOS battery trick can work but it works! My screen start working but now I have a problem with WiFi. I think I did something on disassembling my laptop.

I have an error that wifi is disabled by hardware.

Comment: That's great new. :) In regards to the Wi-Fi, I would suggest going back and carefully checking all connections.

Comment: Okay, works everything. Wifi start working after bios restoring to defaults.
Thank you Michael one more time! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

My latitude keeps emitting an annoying sound. What I tried is super quick fix and worked for me. Here's how.

1. Go dollar store and get an ear-phone (I got a mono-ear-bud )
2. Plug it into ear phone jack on Latitude
3. Beep stops (not during boot up but after the boot)
4. Ear buds still emit annoying beep, so just cut off the bud (all you need is just a plug )
5. Beep goes away!!

Looks as a default, Latitude mutes every sounds if it was plugged a ear phone in its connector. You can still use audio if you have USB audio system (USB doesn't have annoying beep.)

Answer (score 0):

1 Beep:  Replace the motherboard / system board.
2 Beeps: Reseat the memory or replace the memory.
3 Beeps: Replace the motherboard / system board.
4 Beeps: Reseat the memory or replace the memory.
5 Beeps: Replace the CMOS battery.
6 Beeps: Reseat or replace the video card or replace the motherboard / system board.
7 Beeps: Reseat or replace the CPU.
8 Beeps: Reseat the LCD cable or replace the LCD screen.

Answer (score -1):

The laptop beeping is telling you its broken. That is the reason for the beeping. Fixing it will stop the beeping.

It is possible it could be as simple as a loose connection from being dropped. If you are not capable of opening the case yourself, take it to someone who can.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is the LCD cable. I have resolved many Dell 3440 laptops with this error. The cable is damaged somewhere or is only partially connected on one end or the other.

Comment: This duplicates answers already given in at least 2 other answers on this thread. Please read existing answers carefully and avoid posting duplicate information, especially when you don't have anything except the duplicate information to add.